# Chain member initializers

Tags: c++

Is it possible to refer to class members inside "in class initializers"?

Example:

```cpp
struct Example
{
  std::string a = "Hello";
  std::string b = a + "World";
};
```

It seems to work (compiles and runs) but is it ok to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is allowed in default initializers [since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization). Scroll down to the "Usage" section and look at the first example. I copied the explanation and example here for easier reference:

> The name of a non-static data member or a non-static member function can only appear in the following three situations:
>
> 1. As a part of class member access expression, in which the class either has this member or is derived from a class that has this member, including the implicit this-> member access expressions that appear when a non-static member name is used in any of the contexts where this is allowed (inside member function bodies, in member initializer lists, in the in-class default member initializers).

```
struct S
{
    int m;
    int n;
    int x = m;            // OK: implicit this-> allowed in default initializers (C++11)
    S(int i) : m(i), n(m) // OK: implicit this-> allowed in member initializer lists
    {
        this->f();        // explicit member access expression
        f();              // implicit this-> allowed in member function bodies
    }
    void f();
};
```

Comment: Ok I was looking at the paper that introduced them http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm and apparently this is mentioned as a problem there - probably some revision fixed it (can't find an example of this usage) . The cpp reference seems  authoritative enough

Comment: @LorahAttkins I find standards documents to be very hard to read, and cppreference has been my go-to C++ language documentation because it's clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct Example
{
  string a = "Hello";
  string b = a + "World";
};
int main(){
    Example val ;
    val.a = "Salom";
    cout<<val.a<<" "<<val.b; 
}
```

it is okey, you can do it .

but captures the initial result you have If you give **a** a new value **b** will not be updated

[image]